# pandas converting column names to variables efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I do have following dataframe:

```
{'2003-12-02LVDT0023': {0: 2.3407617000000001e-06,
  1: 2.3402380999999998e-06,
  2: 2.3410341000000001e-06,
  3: 2.3417209999999999e-06,
  4: 2.3419282000000002e-06,
  5: 2.3420178e-06,
  6: 2.3424012999999999e-06},
 '2003-12-02LVDT0024': {0: 2.3612594999999998e-06,
  1: 2.3609533999999999e-06,
  2: 2.3611187000000002e-06,
  3: 2.3618049e-06,
  4: 2.3621773999999998e-06,
  5: 2.3626039000000002e-06,
  6: 2.3625455000000001e-06},
 '2003-12-02LVDT0025': {0: 2.3660825000000001e-06,
  1: 2.3660903000000001e-06,
  2: 2.3659481000000001e-06,
  3: 2.3661921e-06,
  4: 2.3668378999999998e-06,
  5: 2.3671985e-06,
  6: 2.3679653999999999e-06},
 '2003-12-02force0023': {0: 2.3664842999999999e-06,
  1: 2.3664650000000002e-06,
  2: 2.3666738999999999e-06,
  3: 2.3665972999999999e-06,
  4: 2.3670195e-06,
  5: 2.3675174999999997e-06,
  6: 2.3677449e-06},
 '2003-12-02force0024': {0: 2.3680921e-06,
  1: 2.3682342000000004e-06,
  2: 2.3684212999999998e-06,
  3: 2.3688697000000001e-06,
  4: 2.3694958999999999e-06,
  5: 2.3698856000000002e-06,
  6: 2.3702362000000002e-06},
 '2003-12-02force0025': {0: 2.3684941000000001e-06,
  1: 2.3691163999999997e-06,
  2: 2.3693348999999999e-06,
  3: 2.3694661000000002e-06,
  4: 2.3701970999999998e-06,
  5: 2.3704627000000002e-06,
  6: 2.3707437000000001e-06}}
```

[image]

I would like to reshape the dataframe in a way, that I do have one column for each data point (the last digits in the headers) and for each data point two additional columns (`lvdt`, and `force`). The dataframe itself has 40000 rows.

What partly works with this tiny data is:

```
# I cannot use `inplace=True` here
new = new.unstack().reset_index()
new['id'] = new.level_0.str[-4:]
new = new.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
new
```

[image]

Which gives me the last four digits of the columns as new column. From here on I might be able to somehow reshape the dataframe. But doing that on the original dataframe results in a new dataframe with 15640000 rows and additional 1 GB of ram consumed.

What I want is a dataframe like:

```
index    force    lvdt    id
0    0.002    0.002    23
1    0.002    0.002    24
```

Comment: Is the last table what you want, and you just want it more efficiently?  Or do you want something different?  If it's the latter it would be good to just write out the desired result in text/tabular form.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you at least close to the dataframe you want:

1. Replace the column index with a hierarchical one:

   ```
   ind = [(t[0:10], t[10:-4], t[-2:]) for t in df.columns]
   newcol = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(ind, names = ['date', 'factor', 'id'])
   df.columns = newcol
   ```
2. use `stack` followed by `reset_index` to convert `date` and `id` column labels into columns:

   ```
   df = df.stack(level=['date', 'id']).reset_index([1,2])
   df.index = range(len(df))
   ```

The last line gives you a unique index.  You could of course also use something meaningful.

Comment: I managed to solve it, but it takes about 2 minutes and 3.2 GB of RAM for the intermediate calculations. I will compare it with your approach.